# JSFiddle Character Count not working when copied to Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

I seem to be going a little mad, I have copied a script from JSFiddle (Found here http://jsfiddle.net/xL3uugux/1/) and below is my Dreamweaver code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    html {
    margin:11px
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text_max = 99;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#textarea').keyup(function () {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="8" cols="30" maxlength="99"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work!! I am guessing this might be really obvious to someone else but I cannot find the problem!

Help, please!

Comment: The browser console (F12) probably presented some errors that would've shown you the problem. For JS debugging, that should be your first stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the jQuery library, for exemple:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In the top-left corner of the jsFiddle window, you can see jQuery version 1.7.1 is used.

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I can mark this as correct I will!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing library or reference. You need jQuery 1.7.1 reference to run this code

```
<script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"/>
```

Use this line in your code .